# Can't find '/opt/local/bin/clang'

Tags: macos, installation, clang, llvm, american-fuzzy-lop

## Background information

I am trying to install AFL on MacOS X, and have been following the instructions on https://reverse.put.as/2017/07/10/compiling-afl-osx-llvm-mode/. 
When I type `$make` in terminal, the following error appears.

`[*] Checking for working 'llvm-config'...
[*] Checking for working '/opt/local/bin/clang'...
[-] Oops, can't find '/opt/local/bin/clang'. Make sure that it's in your $PATH (or set $CC and $CXX).
make: *** [test_deps] Error 1`

I noticed that clang is located in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin. 
Here is the details when I type `clang -v` in terminal:

`Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

## Question

How do I move clang to the following directory '/opt/local/bin/clang'? Or is there any other thing I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try using the `ln -s` command to create a symlink in `/opt/local/bin/` that points to the clang binary in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: I have tried using `ln -s` and it said Permission denied.

Comment: Are you sure the order of your arguments was right?? Because I think even root can't in general create symlinks in /usr/bin because of **SIP**. Make sure it's `sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/your_clang_binary /opt/local/bin/clang`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created opt/local/bin/clang. However, LLVM is still not detecting `opt/local/bin/clang`.

Comment: This is what I get when I make sure clang file is created: `ln: /opt/local/bin/clang: File exists`. And here's the error I have after `make`:  `[*] Checking for working 'llvm-config'...
[*] Checking for working '/opt/local/bin/clang'...
[-] Oops, can't find '/opt/local/bin/clang'. Make sure that it's in your $PATH (or set $CC and $CXX).
make: *** [test_deps] Error 1`.

Comment: What does executing the `clang` command in your terminal  give?? I suspect your clang binary name is in the form`clang-version`. If it is then delete the symlink and recreate it with the correct name of the clang binary